# In need of wiring diagram

Tags: wiring, diagram, dpdt

Could someone link me a simulated circuit wiring diagram for the following circuit: DPDT switch (6 terminals), 2 limit switches,battery pack, motor? I don't have any wiring diagram software.

Comment: You have the "wiring diagram software" embedded right in the question editor. You have the Internet anyway, having hundreds of these.

Comment: We are NOT a design service.  But we generally don't mind helping those that help themselves.  If you put your parts into Google, it does give you appropriate circuits.   You have an idea on what you need.  Use the schematic editor of this site to put one of those circuits into your question.  Explain what you want to do.  Explain what you understand and don't.  Odds are that someone will help, but we tend not to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 4):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFKZW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The complete kit.*

You can add a schematic into your question using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip.

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

If you edit your question to explain what you want these components to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck then further help may be forthcoming.

Comment: ROFL You didn't simulate it for him!

Comment: I've just realised that there's no ground included in the kit. Oh-oh!

Comment: Perfectly designed; right to the specifications.